# preg_match and accented characters

Tags: php, regex

I have a problem. The word "lyža" has 4 characters. When I use the "strlen" command it gives 5 characters. I can handle this by using "iconv_strlen".
But if I want to use the "preg_match" command. So he finds another position. The problem is illustrated by the following code. In both cases there are dashes at 4 positions. The accented character makes a problem.

```
$line = 'lyza------';
preg_match('/[-]+/', $line, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches);

$line2 = 'lyža------';
preg_match('/[-]+/', $line2, $matches2, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
print_r($matches2);
```

Comment: Just count the number of chars in the match with `mb_strlen`.

Comment: `ž` is one character, but two bytes. And `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` also counts in bytes. See also: [What Every Programmer Absolutely, Positively Needs To Know About Encodings And Character Sets To Work With Text](http://kunststube.net/encoding/)

Comment: I need a position

Comment: You can use [`mb_strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strpos.php) to get the location of the first dash. This will account for unicode characters.

Comment: What I wrote above is only a partial problem. I need to find the position, say:  ([-]+[a-z]+[-]+)